# content-disposition header being sent twice....once by code the other unknown

Tags: .net, iis, http-headers, content-disposition

I have an .aspx page where I'm manually setting headers to force a download of a pdf file.  It works fine in IE, but in chrome and firefox 8.0, it's giving an error.

I finally tracked down the source of the problem to the content-disposition header being sent twice but I have no idea how or why it's being set the first time.

The first instance of the header is just:
Content-disposition: Attachment
The second is:
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=download.pdf  <-- this one set by code

is IIS taking over somehow and adding this first instance of the header?  If so, how can I toggle it to NOT do that?

EDIT: adding the code that sets the headers

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
                Response.WriteFile(fname);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
```

Comment: Could you post the code you know is setting one of them? Also, are you sure it's not being executed twice?

Comment: added the code that sets the headers...and I'm POSITIVE it's not being executed twice.

Comment: Wild guess: check what happens if you don't set the type. Unrelated: your code will do the wrong thing for filenames that contain whitespace, non-ASCII, etc... See RFC 6266.

Comment: removed the type declaration...no change.

Comment: Are you running this locally? If so, do you have any custom HttpModules that may be adding it? It's a weird thought, but this is a weird problem.

Comment: no, it's on a dedicated server.  I copied the code exactly to another server and it works perfectly.  The only wildcard here (that I can think of) is that the server that's problematic is actually serving the files from another machine using a UNC path in IIS for the home directory.  That's the only thing I can see that's different between the non-working and working environments unless there's some kind of MIME-Type setting in IIS that's forcing a content-disposition set buried deeply inside IIS :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in IIS the  HTTP Headers section for that page. Make sure it's not set there.

IIS6: http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2009/03/23/force-ie7-compatibility-mode-in-ie8-with-iis-settings.aspx

IIS7: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133(WS.10).aspx

Comment: this was it.  Now need to find out from the business why it was set this way.  Thanks much.